# How can I do dynamic assignment to a struct inside a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, dynamic

Currently I am making dynamic allocation of structs within structs in C++. So, I made a code that can be dynamically allocated that I think.
Here is the code that I made it :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int cnt = 0;
struct num{
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct name {
    char Stu[30] = { 0 };
    num *number;
};

int input(int& a) {
    if (cnt == 0) {
        cout << "입력할 수 : ";
        cin >> a;
        cnt++;
        return a;
    }
    if (cnt == 1) {
        cout << "입력할 수 : ";
        cin >> a;
        cnt++;
    }
}

void input(char *pt) {
    if (cnt == 2) {
        cout << "입력할 글자 : ";
        cin >> pt;
        cnt++;
    }
}

int inputnum(int i) {
    cout << "할당할 숫자를 쓰시오 : ";
    cin >> i;
    return i;
}

void printdata(name *pSt, int i, int j) {
    cout << pSt[i].number[j].x << endl;
    cout << pSt[i].number[j].y << endl;
    cout << pSt[i].Stu << endl;
}

int main() {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    num1 = inputnum(num1);
    num2 = inputnum(num2);
    name* student = new name[num1];
    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num2; j++) {
            student[i].number = new num[num2];
            input(student[i].number[j].x);
            input(student[i].number[j].y);
            input(student[i].Stu);
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num2; j++) {
            printdata(student, i, j);
        }
    }

}
```

But if I input more than 2 in num2, output number is weird like -842150451.
How can I do dynamic assignment to a struct inside a struct in C++?

Comment: What's the purpose of having to supply `i` to the function `int inputnum(int i)`? Why not define a local `i` inside the function instead? When it comes to doing manual dynamic allocation, your program leaks memory. Read [the rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: `int input(int &a)` doesn't return anything if `cnt != 0`, that's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

First, use `std::string` instead of `char[30]`. Second, don't allocate memory unless is necessarily. There is no need for `num* number`. Use a `std::vector`.

You can put your code as follows:

```cpp
struct num {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct name {
    std::string      Stu;
    std::vector<num> number;
};
```

`-842150451` is not a weird number. It's decimal for 0xCDCDCDCD. This is a value used by Microsoft debug CRT to represent uninitialized heap memory. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#cite_ref-Win32CRTDebugHeapInternals_23-2).

Concerning the `input` functions, why don't you write some simpler functions?

```cpp
void input_x(int& x)
{
    cout << "입력할 수 : ";
    cin >> x;
}

void input_y(int& y)
{
    cout << "입력할 수 : ";
    cin >> y;
}

void input_s(char *pt)
{
    cout << "입력할 글자 : ";
    cin >> pt;
}
```

Which you can use as follows:

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num2; j++) {
            student[i].number = new num[num2];
            input_x(student[i].number[j].x);
            input_y(student[i].number[j].y);
            input_s(student[i].Stu);
        }
    }
```

The `input_s` should use `std::string`, though, if you use what I suggest above:

```cpp
void input_s(std::string& pt)
{
    cout << "입력할 글자 : ";
    cin >> pt;
}
```

As for `name* student` you can replace that with `std::vector<name>`:

```cpp
    std::vector<name> student;
    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num2; j++) {
            name s;
            s.number.resize(num2);
            input(s.number[j].x);
            input(s.number[j].y);
            input(s.Stu);
            student.push_back(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I don't know about vector container, that's why I can't do more simple. I will study more about C++ programming! Thank you for your advise.